# How to get a value from a particular row from the last using r

Tags: r

I want to get a value from a particular row from the last. I have tried this so far and used tail function to get last two values

```
> x <- sample(1:40, 10, replace=F)
> x
 [1] 17 35 18  4 12 23 36 29 22 16
> y<-tail(x,2)
> y
[1] 22 16
```

Using the tail function we get last two values 22 and 16 But I only want first value that is 22. I know it has an easy solution but i am not able to find it.

Comment: You can do `x[length(x)-1]` or `tail(x, 2)[1]`

Comment: @RichardScriven thanks for the quick reply

Comment: using dplyr function nth, gives you: `nth(x, (length(x)-1))`. If it is always the same position, replace (length(x)-1) by the position number

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be easily solved by length function.

`x[length(x)-1]` should give you second last value.